# Repositories specified in pom.xml are not used by maven?

Tags: maven, repository

I am compiling HBase using Maven3.

The pom from github https://github.com/cloudera/hbase/blob/cdh4-0.94.2_4.2.1/pom.xml specified some repositories to provide some external jars. But maven 3 doesn't look for jars from these repositories and just throws exception says the jar is not found from mirror.

Here is the repositories from pom.

```
  <repositories>
<repository>
  <id>cdh.repo</id>
  <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos</url>
  <name>Cloudera Repositories</name>
  <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
  </snapshots>
</repository>

<repository>
  <id>cdh.snapshots.repo</id>
  <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local</url>
  <name>Cloudera Snapshots Repository</name>
  <snapshots>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
  </snapshots>
  <releases>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
  </releases>
</repository>
<repository>
  <id>apache release</id>
  <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/releases/</url>
</repository>
<repository>
  <id>apache non-releases</id>
  <name>Apache non-releases</name>
  <url>http://people.apache.org/~stack/m2/repository</url>
  <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
  </snapshots>
  <releases>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
  </releases>
</repository>
<repository>
  <id>java.net</id>
  <name>Java.Net</name>
  <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
  <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
  </snapshots>
  <releases>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
  </releases>
</repository>
<repository>
  <id>codehaus</id>
  <name>Codehaus Public</name>
  <url>http://repository.codehaus.org/</url>
  <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
  </snapshots>
  <releases>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
  </releases>
</repository>
<repository>
  <id>repository.jboss.org</id>
  <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
  <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
  </snapshots>
</repository>
<repository>
  <id>ghelmling.testing</id>
  <name>Gary Helmling test repo</name>
  <url>http://people.apache.org/~garyh/mvn/</url>
  <snapshots>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
  </snapshots>
  <releases>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
  </releases>
</repository>
```

-----------------------updated 2013-11-28 13:53----------------------------

My bad. The problem is

```
  <mirrors>
    <mirror> 
        <id>public</id>
        <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
<url>http://mavenrepo.mycorp.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/public</url>
    </mirror> 
  </mirrors>
```

`<mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>` should be `<mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>`. By using *, it will be used to handle all download request of all repos. And surely the repo of company doesn't mirror 3rd part repos resources

Comment: Can you paste the logs here ? I would like to see a couple of things in the logs.

Comment: Without the full `pom.xml` and the output, people won't be able to help you much. Please polish up your question and add more info. Do you have a `settings.xml` which defines `<mirrors/>`...?

Comment: Thanks carlspring! The problem is due to my bad configuration of mirror.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Posting my guess as an answer.

Your problem seems to be that in your `settings.xml` you have a `<mirrors/>` section which is overriding the repositories defined in your `pom.xml`.

Comment: Can this be an issue [**IFF**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if#:~:text=In%20logic%20and%20related%20fields,true%20or%20both%20are%20false.) within the `<mirrors>...<mirrors/>` section there are these repos - or contrary - whatever the mirrors are, one should put there even all the repos that are already in the pom.xml ?